# replacing NA's with 0's in R dataframe

Tags: r

I've been playing around with the airquality dataset in R and figuring out how to remove lines with missing values.  I used the following command:

```
complete.cases(airquality)
AQ1<-airquality[complete.cases(airquality),]
```

How do I go about replacing the NA's in airquality with 0's and then creating a new dataframe, AQ2?

P.S. Does my command above create a new dataframe called AQ1?

Thanks

Comment: You can use: `airquality[is.na(airquality)] <- 0`

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
dataset <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), 5);
data <- as.data.frame(dataset)
```

> ```
> [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] 
> [1,]    2    3    5    5    4
> [2,]    2    4    3    2    4
> [3,]    2   NA   NA   NA    2
> [4,]    2    3   NA    5    5
> [5,]    2    3    2    2    3
> ```

```
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 27):

What Tyler Rinker says is correct:

```
AQ2 <- airquality
AQ2[is.na(AQ2)] <- 0
```

will do just this.

What you are originally doing is that you are taking from `airquality` all those rows (cases) that are complete. So, all the cases that do not have any NA's in them, and keep only those.

Answer (score 10):

Here are two quickie approaches I know of:

**In base**

```
AQ1 <- airquality
AQ1[is.na(AQ1 <- airquality)] <- 0
AQ1
```

**Not in base**

```
library(qdap)
NAer(airquality)
```

PS `P.S. Does my command above create a new dataframe called AQ1?`

Look at AQ1 and see

Comment: Yes, it does when I look at AQ1.  Sorry, I must seem like a real loser asking simple stuff like this, but I'm really new to R.  I'm good with stats, just never through a program like this.  I've come a long way in the last couple of days though.

Comment: Not at all we start somewhere but the best way I've learned is to try it and see.  Everything in R is an object you can look at.  Surround objects with `str`, `names` and `summary` and you'll learn a ton of things.

Comment: Agreed, or put `?` before it to get help documentation on the object, and `??` before it to search for the word in the documentation.